# Problem in ContactsContract API android

Tags: android

i have an HTC legend.In its phone contacts it shows 4-5 contacts.But when i query it in my application it shows nearly 45 contacts.I think its  gmail contacts.

> ```
>    String[] Projection = new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts._ID, 
>             ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME, 
>             ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_ID,
>             ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER,
>             ContactsContract.Contacts.STARRED};
> ```
>
> Cursor cursor = managedQuery(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, Projection, null, null, null);

I am getting all the details with photo as well in a listview. Now i need to get particular contact details like all his phone numbers,emails,photo etc.For this i am writing this query

> ```
>     final String[] projection = new String[] {
>             ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID,
>             ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
>             ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
>             ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.IS_PRIMARY,
>     };
>     final Cursor phone = managedQuery(
>             ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,  
>             projection,
>             ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + "=?",
>             new String[]{contactId},
>             null);
> ```

```
> if(phone.moveToFirst()) {
>             final int contactNumberColumnIndex =
> phone.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
>             final int contactTypeColumnIndex =
> phone.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE);
```

i am getting all the details of the phone contact but not all other contacts.
i have read that all these details are stored in  shared table(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI), but i am not getting exactly  what to do go get this done.

Can someone help me figure out how to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
getContentResolver().query(
    RawContactsEntity.CONTENT_URI,

    // projection
    new String[] {
        BaseColumns._ID,
        RawContactsEntity.MIMETYPE,

        // DATA columns are interpreted according to MIMETYPE
        // Project only union of data columns needed
        RawContactsEntity.DATA1,
        RawContactsEntity.DATA2,
        RawContactsEntity.DATA3,
        RawContactsEntity.DATA4,
        RawContactsEntity.DATA7,
        RawContactsEntity.DATA9,
        RawContactsEntity.DATA10,
    },

    // selection
    RawContactsEntity.DELETED + "<>1 AND " + 
    RawContactsEntity.MIMETYPE + " IN ('" + 
    StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "','" + 
    Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "','" + 
    Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "','" + 
    StructuredPostal.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "','" + 
    Organization.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "')",

    // selection params
    null,

    // sorting
    null);
```

Next iterate through cursor, and first read MIME type:

```
final String mimeType = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(
    RawContactsEntity.MIMETYPE));
```

And depends on MIME type read corresponding data kind:

```
if (StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE.equals(mimeType)) {
    readNameData(cursor);
} else if (Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE.equals(mimeType)) {
    addEmailData(cursor);
}
```

and so on.

Comment: very useful, for lazy dev like me.